# AWK Search Fact itself in same File

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a file where

data is

```
90|123456|.. some more fields
90|654321|... some more fields
.... some more lines starting with 90
91|123456|.. some more fields
91|654321|... some more fields
.... some more lines starting with 91
92|123456|.. some more fields
92|654321|... some more fields
.... some more lines starting with 92
```

2nd Field is Key value for me
& it will have 90,91 & 92 values in start field

```
90|keyvalue will always be there
91|keyvalue .. not mendatory
92|keyvalue .. not mendatory
```

expected output is

```
90|keyvalue [Mendatory]
91|keyvalue --> print if exist in file
92|keyvalue --> print if exist in file
```

for all key values

what i did was

```
grep "^90" origfilename |awk -F '|' '{print $2}'> temp90.txt #this gives me all keyvalues

awk '{print "90|"$0"|"}' temp90.txt >> temp90-1.txt
awk '{print "91|"$0"|"}' temp90.txt >> temp90-1.txt
awk '{print "92|"$0"|"}' temp90.txt >> temp90-1.txt

grep -f temp90-1.txt origfilename
```

This gets me output But I think its not proper efficient way to do this

How to do this on single awk or other way

Comment: Are you just trying to sort your file based on the first two fields? Or split the file based on the first two fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F'|' 'NR==FNR && /^90/  {k[$2]} 
             NR!=FNR && $2 in k{print}' file{,}

90|123456|.. some more fields
90|654321|... some more fields
91|123456|.. some more fields
91|654321|... some more fields
92|123456|.. some more fields
92|654321|... some more fields
```

**Explanation** In the first scan get the keys and in the second scan print the lines with a matching key.  Note that `file{,}` is the same as `file file` for `awk` to double scan the input file.

Comment: Brilliant!! +1, Let me try once & check

Comment: When the data starts with all 90 lines, you can do it in one scan.